# How to encode an MSMQ Message as UTF8

Tags: c++, encoding, ascii, msmq

I have a C++ application that can send and receive messages. All works and not a problem however i noticed that the messages being placed on the response queue are encoded with the UTF16 type.

I am currently getting the response messages in the UTF16 format. How do i make it so these messages are encoded with ASCII or UTF8 ? The source file passed in is type UTF8 but i keep getting UTF16 messages out.

I am using the _bstr_t as the type which ive read up on and is causing the UTF-16 encoding , ive tried changing the type to all sorts of different but i cannot get the encoding type to change

Thanks

Comment: What type did you use when you wrote the message to the queue?

Comment: Solved this. Converted the bstr message into an array of bytes (1 byte) and then passed this message over instead of the bstr which is (2 bytes per char)

Comment: @PowPowPowell thanks! saved me so much time